# Symbolically replace part of expression if that expression meets a condition

Tags: pattern-matching

Say I have an expression like

`expr = g1[i1, j1] h1[k, l] f1[i, j1, k1, l] + g2[k1, j] f2[i, l, k1, l1] + f3[i, j, l, l1] + ...`

and in each term above I want to do some transformations such that the `f` functions inputs are `f[i,j,k,l]`. For example one transformation for the `f2` term would be `{l->j, j->l}`, changing the f2 term to g2[k1, l] f2[i, j, i, l1]. Note that the inputs of the other functions in the same term must also undergo the same transformations.

I've been attempting this by doing something along the lines of

```
patt = pre_. f_[I1_,I2_,I3_,I4_] post_.
Map[(# // With[{
      I1 = Cases[{#}, patt -> I1][[1]],
      I2 = Cases[{#}, patt -> I2][[1]],
      I3 = Cases[{#}, patt -> I3][[1]],
      I4 = Cases[{#}, patt -> I4][[1]]},
     Which[
         !(I1 === i), ReplaceAll[{i -> I1, I1 -> i}],
         !(I2 === j), ReplaceAll[{j -> I2, I2 -> j}],
         !(I2 === k), ReplaceAll[{k -> I3, I3 -> k}],
         !(I2 === l), ReplaceAll[{l -> I4, I4 -> l}],
     ]]) &, expr]
```

The idea here is to, on a term by term basis, identify the input positions which are incorrect and flip what's in that position with the correct symbol.

This might work if `Which` went through all the conditionals rather than stopping on the first one and if I had something to chain apply the resulting list of `ReplaceAll` functions. Case does not seem to to be the right tool to use here either, but after scouring the documentation for a more appropriate function I came up with nothing.

Comment: Something like: `Replace[expr, 
 subexpr : ___ f2[___] :> 
  Replace[subexpr, {l -> j, j -> l}, {2}], {1}]`?

Comment: Thank you, the : was just what I needed. Currently my solution to this problem is Replace[expr, subexpr : pre_. f_[I1_, I2_, I3_, I4_] post_. :> ReplaceAll[subexpr, {i -> I1, I1 -> i, j -> I2, I2 -> j, k -> I3, I3 -> k, l -> I4, I4 -> l}], {1}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example:

```
expr = g1[i1, j1] h1[k, l] f1[i, j1, k1, l] + g2[k1, j] f2[i, l, k1, l1] + f3[i, j, l, l1]

(* f3[i, j, l, l1] + f2[i, l, k1, l1] g2[k1, j] + f1[i, j1, k1, l] g1[i1, j1] h1[k, l] *)
```

you can do

```
Replace[expr, subexpr : ___ f2[___] :> Replace[subexpr, {l -> j, j -> l}, {2}], {1}]

(* f3[i, j, l, l1] + f2[i, j, k1, l1] g2[k1, l] + f1[i, j1, k1, l] g1[i1, j1] h1[k, l] *)
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the general case I was looking for, but it sent me down the right track.